# Using a status colour on the front-end

Tags: templates, status

Is there a way to retrieve the colour assigned to a status to use on a front-end template?

For instance, I have an ecommerce system that uses a status of "Declined". I have made this status display in red so on the  back end the store administrator can easily see any declined transactions.

Now, say I wanted to output a list of a customer's transactions for them on the front end. Would it be possible to grab that colour to use in my template or will I need to create a series of conditionals and set colours that way (using CSS classes)?

I guess a quick hack around it would be to do something like

```
<p class="{status}">Status: {status}</p>
```

Comment: It might be good to add prefix to the class -- "status-{status}" -- but that's obviously just preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, my friend. Your suggestion of code is the best option.